# Pasar un objeto en RouterLink Angular

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Tengo dos componentes, mi componente A tiene un objeto llamado Microfono. En este componente A tengo un boton para ir al Componente B, para hacer esto lo hago con el [RouterLink]. Pero quiero pasarle mi objeto Microfono que tengo en mi componente A a mi componente B. ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

[image: Este seria mi componente A. Yo tengo ese codigo HTML donde tengo un NgFor y dentro de eso tengo una variable mic de mi lista de microfonos. Yo necesito pasar ese mic a mi componente B]

[image: Este es el .ts de mi componente A.]

[image: Y este es mi componente B necesito que este componente reciba mi objeto mic del componente A. Ese INPUT fue un intento de tratar de recibir mi objeto mic]

```
    <button class="titulo navbar-toggler color1 fw-700 redondeado sombra" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" attr.data-target="#desplegable-{{id+1}}">
            <div class="texto-boton">
                    <i class="fas fa-guitar"></i> | {{listaMicrofono.nombreClasificacion}}
            </div>
        </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="desplegable-{{id+1}}">
    <div class="row botones-desplegables">
        <div *ngFor="let mic of listaMicrofono.microfonos">
            <button type="button" class="item btn color1 fw-700 sombra">{{mic.nombre}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  @Input()id:any;
  @Input()listaMicrofono:clasificacionMicrofonos;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.listaMicrofono.microfonos);
  }
}
```

```
  @Input()microfono:Microfono;
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que en vez de imágenes subas el código. Saludos!

Comment: Ahi los agregue!